# Aligning Excel Tables in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I've a number of tables in Excel that I need to drop into PowerPoint. The tables are various lengths, from 10 to 15 rows long (always same # of columns).

Code I am using to get the table into PowerPoint:

```vb
Set rng = Sheets("Table Example").Range("V8:AA16")
rng.Copy

oPPTFile.Slides(5).Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteHTML
Set myshape = oPPTFile.Slides(5).Shapes(oPPTFile.Slides(5).Shapes.Count)

With myshape
    .Top = 10
    .Height = 360
    .Left = 20
    .Width = 650
End With
```

This repeats for three different tables based on what the user chooses. It will pick up the table from the location in Excel and drop it into the slide.

In the slidedeck preview, it shows the table in one location. In the slide itself, it shows it in another, and regardless, it is not aligned properly.

I can ask the users to click and drag the table into the preset drop spot that PowerPoint does to align with other objects in the slide, but for completeness I am trying to get the tables to automatically drop into that location.

Done a ton of searching but couldn't find the right code for my application. I'm not an experienced coder by any means.